# How do I strip $1 argument in .zshrc?

Tags: zsh

I am using the following line to try

```
alias cc="echo mydoma.in/notes/$1"
```

The result I get

```
mydoma.in/notes/ test
```

The result I'm expecing

```
mydoma.in/notes/test
```

What I've tried

- alias cc="echo mydoma.in/notes/$(echo -n $1 | xargs)"
- alias cc="echo mydoma.in/notes/$(echo \'$1\')"
- alias cc="echo mydoma.in/notes/$(echo '$1' | sed 's/[[:space:]]//g')"
- alias cc="echo 'mydoma.in/notes/'$1"

They all return the same thing.

I appreciate any help you can give me.

Comment: Aliases can't use parameters. Use a function instead.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is to use a function. Thank you, @that_other_guy.

```
func () {
        echo "mydoma.in/notes/$1"
}
alias cc="func $1"
```

Comment: That's still the wrong way to use the alias, which isn't needed anymore anyway.  `cc () { echo "myxoma.in/notes/$1" }`, then `cc test`.